# How do I draw a horizontal line between two circles with CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

How do I draw a horizontal line in between 2 circles in CSS?

It has to be in the middle of them just as shown in the screenshot.

Example here:

[image]

I have drawn the 2 circles, but don't know how to connect them.

```css
#status-buttons a {
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  min-width: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#status-buttons a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#status-buttons a.active span {
  color: white;
  background: #ACCF5B;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.792157) 3px 3px 3px 0;
}
#status-buttons span {
  color: white;
  background: #22bacb;
  display: block;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.792157) 3px 3px 3px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="status-buttons" class="text-center">
  <a href="#/form/regalo" class="active"><span>1</span> Step 1</a>
  <a href="#/form/tusdatos"><span>2</span> Step 2</a>
</div>
```

See [demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nerlijma/s5x2kmmz/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a pseudo-element to insert an absolutely-positioned border:

```css
#status-buttons {
  position: relative;          /* 1 */
  display: inline-block;       /* 2 */
}
#status-buttons::after {       /* 3 */
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: -1;                 /* 4 */
  top: 35%;
  left: 25%;
  border: 3px solid #ACCF5B;
}
#status-buttons a {
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  min-width: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#status-buttons a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#status-buttons a.active span {
  color: white;
  background: #ACCF5B;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.792157) 3px 3px 3px 0;
}
#status-buttons span {
  color: white;
  background: #22bacb;
  display: block;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.792157) 3px 3px 3px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="status-buttons" class="text-center">
  <a href="#/form/regalo" class="active"><span>1</span> Step 1</a>
  <a href="#/form/tusdatos"><span>2</span> Step 2</a>
</div>
```

Notes:

1. [Establish nearest positioned ancestor for absolute positioning.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning)
2. Make container consume only the width necessary.
3. Insert pseudo element
4. Ensure that any horizontal line overlap doesn't appear above circles

Comment: Thanks! awesome. I changed it to the link element, so it can handle multiple steps https://jsfiddle.net/nerlijma/s5x2kmmz/10/ in case it helps anybody!

Comment: @nerlijma you can change the rule to `#status-buttons a:not(:last-child)::after` if you don't want the line extending from the final link

Comment: @DaveMongoose Great suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new element and position it between the two circles:

```css
#status-buttons a {
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    min-width: 150px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#status-buttons a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
    
#status-buttons a.active span {
    color: white;
    background: #ACCF5B;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.792157) 3px 3px 3px 0;
}

#status-buttons span {
    color: white;
    background: #22bacb;
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.792157) 3px 3px 3px 0;
}

#line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  left: 112px;
  width: 96px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #ACCF5B;
}
```

```html
<div id="status-buttons" class="text-center">
                <a href="#/form/regalo" class="active"><span>1</span> Step 1</a>
                <div id="line">
                </div>
                <a href="#/form/tusdatos"><span>2</span> Step 2</a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/sfyuxrs9/

It contains a `div` (which forms the line) which has `position: absolute`and a negative `z-index` value. The rest ist just adjusting all the values for width/height/top and left

Answer (score 2):

Here's the cleanest solution with `flex`

```css
.timeline {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circle {
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.dashed {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px dashed #C4C4C4;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="dashed"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="dashed"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very clean solution!!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do some thing like this
check the following code snippet

```css
#status-buttons a {
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    min-width: 150px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#status-buttons a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
    
#status-buttons a.active span {
    color: white;
    background: #ACCF5B;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.792157) 3px 3px 3px 0;
}

#status-buttons span {
    color: white;
    background: #22bacb;
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.792157) 3px 3px 3px 0;
}

div.linetop { border-top: 1px solid #111111; width:95px;
position:absolute;
  top:40px;
  left:115px;
}
```

```html
<div id="status-buttons" class="text-center">
                <a href="#/form/regalo" class="active"><span>1</span> Step 1</a>
 
                <a href="#/form/tusdatos"><span>2</span> Step 2</a>
            </div>


<div class="linetop"></div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
<div id="status-buttons" class="text-center">
    <a href="#/form/regalo" class="active"><span>1</span> Step 1</a>
    <a href="#/form/tusdatos"><span>2</span> Step 2</a>
</div>
<div class="line">
</div>
```

The CSS

```
 #status-buttons a {
    position: relative;
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    min-width: 150px;
    text-decoration: none;
        z-index: 1;
}

#status-buttons a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#status-buttons a.active span {
    color: white;
    background: #ACCF5B;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.792157) 3px 3px 3px 0;
}

#status-buttons span {
    color: white;
    background: #22bacb;
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.792157) 3px 3px 3px 0;

}
.line {
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    width: 20%;
    left: 71px;
    top: 39px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/nwjz2010/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this method :)

```css
.his-bar { display: flex; position: relative; padding-top: 50px; width: 100%; margin:auto; margin-top: 40px; }

.his-bar:before { content: ''; border: 1px solid #727272; position: absolute; top: 60px; right: 0; width: 99%; }

.his-bar .point { border: 2px solid #872071; width: 20px; height: 20px; border-radius: 50%; display: inline-block; background-color: #F8F8F8; z-index: 2; position: relative; }

.his-bar .point-start:after { content: '2000'; position: absolute; top: 30px; left: -7px; }

.his-bar .point-end { margin-left: auto; }

.his-bar .point-end:after { content: '2021'; position: absolute; top: 30px; left: -7px; }
```

```html
 <div class="his-bar">
     <span class="point point-start"></span>
     <span class="point point-end"></span>
 </div>
```